# C# Sort list of class properties based on another List strings

Tags: c#, sorting, reflection

I loop through the list of properties using reflection and assign the table cell that value. My class properties that are being looped through are assigned to the wrong column (header).

How do I sort the dataList properties names based on the header list? They are both named the same. I would rather do it this way than sort header list based on properties.

dataList type will always be a class with properties.

```
public void SetTableStrong<T>(List<T> dataList, List<string> header)
{       
    // Define our columns
    Column c = null;
    foreach (var item in header)
    {
        c = table.addTextColumn(item);
        c.horAlignment = Column.HorAlignment.CENTER;
    }

    // Initialize Your Table
    table.initialize();
    table.data.Clear();

    foreach (var item in dataList.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }))
    {
        Datum d = Datum.Body(item.index.ToString());

        //Property set to wrong header because they are not sorted to the same as headers.
        foreach (var property in item.value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(item.value, null);

            if (value == null)
                continue;

            d.elements.Add(value.ToString());
        }
        table.data.Add(d);
    }

    // Draw Your Table
    table.startRenderEngine();
}
```

Comment: i was wondering which `table` package you're using?

Comment: @JoeBlow https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/42831

Table Pro for Unity3D

Comment: thanks for that!  we built our own once ... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to add all properties to a `Dictionary<string,string>` first, and then loop the columns, and pick the corresponding value from the dictionary:

```
var propValueByName = item
    .value
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(p => new {
        p.Name
    ,   Val = p.GetValue(item.value, null)
    }).Where(p => p.Val != null)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Val.ToString());
```

Now loop the columns, and add `propValueByName[columnName]` to `d.elements`:

```
foreach (var columnName : header) {
    d.elements.Add(propValueByName[columnName]);
}
table.data.Add(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cache your properties and then fetch them in the same order than your headers.

```
private static Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]> TypeProperties
    = new Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>();
public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetTypeProperties<T>()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo[] properties;
    if (!TypeProperties.TryGetValue(type, out properties))
        TypeProperties.Add(type, properties = type.GetProperties());
    return properties;
}

/* Fixed excerpt from your code */

var properties = GetTypeProperties<T>();
foreach (var hdr in header)
{
    var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == hdr);
    if (property != null)
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(item.value, null);
        if (value==null) //Doesn't this also mess the order?
            continue;
        d.elements.Add(value.ToString());
    }
}
table.data.Add(d);
```